# Python - Json Conversion - Why does it behave different using similar string format

Tags: python, json, string, dictionary

I have a question on converting a python string to a dict using json.loads. Then convert the dict into a json_string using the function below:

```
def JsonConvert(StringInput):
    #convert string to dict
    DictTmp=json.loads(StringInput)

    #convert dict to json_string
    json_string=json.dumps(DictTmp)

    #return JSON string
    return json_string
```

So using the function above, I feed the following string as an example:

```
stringt= ''' { "result": { "Energy": { "biggest_gainer": { "equity": 
    "Hornbeck Offshore", "change": 0.27 }, "biggest_loser": { "equity": 
    "CIRCOR Intl., Inc.", "change": -8.92 }, "change": -1.23 } } }'''
```

but as soon as I replace some items with string variables the Json conversion throws the error below:

```
stringt= ''' { "result": { "Energy": { "biggest_gainer": { "equity": 
    "%s", "change": %s }, "biggest_loser": { "equity": "%s", "change": %s 
    }, "change": %s } } }'''%(Energy_gain_equity,Energy_gain_change,
    Energy_loss_equity,Energy_loss_change,sector_Energy)
```

Gives the following error:

```
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-60-0d59da63c634> in <module>()
    152     #print(type(json_string))
    153 
--> 154 print(google_sector_report())

<ipython-input-60-0d59da63c634> in google_sector_report()
    149 
    150     string = stringer()
--> 151     json_string = JsonConvert(string)
    152     #print(type(json_string))
    153 

<ipython-input-60-0d59da63c634> in JsonConvert(StringInput)
    137     def JsonConvert(StringInput):
    138         #convert string to dict
--> 139         DictTmp=json.loads(StringInput)
    140 
    141         print(type(DictTmp))

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, 
object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, 
**kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is 
None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    337 
    338         """
--> 339         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):

/anaconda/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, 
err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 23 (char 146)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

on request of koalo hereby the full output string printed in jupyter:

```
{
  "result": {
    "Energy": {
      "biggest_gainer": {
        "equity": "McDermott International",
        "change": +0.33
      },
      "biggest_loser": {
        "equity": "Bill Barrett Corporation",
        "change": -0.43
      },
      "change": -1.48
    },
    "Basic Materials": {
      "biggest_gainer": {
        "equity": "Gold Fields Limited (ADR)",
        "change": +0.11
      },
      "biggest_loser": {
        "equity": "Jaguar Mining Inc (USA)",
        "change": -0.74
      },
      "change": -0.35
    },
    "Industrials": {
      "biggest_gainer": {
        "equity": "LML Payment Systems, Inc.",
        "change": +21.7
      },
      "biggest_loser": {
        "equity": "Chicago Bridge & Iron Co",
        "change": -1.80
      },
      "change": -0.46
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: hi koalo, the full output string is included in the question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>     "change": +0.33
> ```

I don't know how that `+` ended up there, but it's invalid JSON. There's another further down.

I don't know why you're constructing JSON using string methods when you already know about `json.dumps` and so on.

Comment: Ah thanks, that indeed solved it. I changed the numbers in to floats before adding it to the string. So now it works. But i guess you mean with your question that using the string adjustments is not the optimal way correct? It is actually the first time I work with these libraries and json, and looking back at it, it would have been easier to just construct the dict instead of adding the string to my code. I guess that would have been better?

Comment: @MikeH: yes, JSON is a format for data exchange, in your code it's much easier to just work with Python dictionaries and Python values and then use json.dumps at the end to turn it into JSON.